# How many gates are necessary to implement an arbitrary n-qubit permutation unitary?

Tags: quantum-gate, complexity-theory, gate-synthesis

How many gates are necessary to implement an arbitrary n-qubit permutation unitary, using only 1- and 2-qubit gates?

An n-qubit permutation unitary is a $2^n$ x $2^n$ unitary matrix where each entry is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Note that there are $(2^n)!$ permutations, which implies a (roughly) exponential number of gates is needed.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Can you explain why this means that it cannot be done in polynomial number of gates?

Comment: Parameter counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea of parameter counting, suggested by @NorbertSchuch, I was able to find more information on that topic and work out a proof that the number of required gates is indeed exponential.

The proof goes as follows. Assume that we have some way to implement an arbitrary n-qubit permutation unitary gate. Each such gate defines some permutation of the state space, so there is a total of $O(2^n!)$ different matrices for this gate. The implementing circuit has to be different for each such matrix.

Assume further that we have some constant number of 1- and 2-qubits gates available to us that does not depend on $n$. There is $O(n)$ ways to select the placement for a 1-qubit gate, and $O(n^2)$ ways to select the placement for a 2-qubit gate. Therefore, there is no more than $O(n^{2m})$ ways to place $m$ gates in the circuit.

To match the total number of possible permutation unitaries, the total number of gates has to be such that $O(n^{2m})=O(2^n!)$. Taking logarithm on both sides, and using Stirling's approximation, one can show that this implies that $m=O(\frac{n2^n}{\log{n}})$, i.e. $m$ is exponential, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Can't you decompose it into $n - r$ swaps, where $r$ is the number of disjoint cycles in the permutation's [cycle decomposition](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_for_permutations)?

Comment: @ChrisD, I want to permute computational basis states, not qubits.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then.